# Solving a difficult differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, functions, physics, code-request, code-generation

I've the following DE, describing a physical phenomenon. And the prupose is to solve that DE using Mathematica

$$x(t)\cdot r+x'(t)\cdot l+a\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{x(t)}{b}\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x(t)=\dots$$

The intial conditon is equal to $x(0)=x_0$ which is bigger than zero.

For the constants:

- $r$ can be very large;
- $l$ can be very large;
- $a$ is round about $0.02526$;
- $b$ is very small, round about $300\cdot10^{-6}$;
- $x_0$ can be very large

How can I solve $x(t)$ for general the general constants?!

Comment: Are you worried about numerical issues when your parameters get very large and very small? In that case, a re-parametrization may help: set $s=t\cdot r/l$ as the new "scaled time" and $y(s)=x(t)/b$ as the reparametrized function, to find the differential equation
$$
y(s)+y'(s)+A\cdot\ln(1+y(s))=0
$$
with the constant $A=\frac{a}{b r}$ and the initial condition $y(0)=x_0/b$. Likely in this form the size of the single parameter $A$ is less of a numerical issue.

Comment: @Roman: See addition to my answer where no reparametrization is used.

Comment: After re-parametrization, if $y_0$ turns out to be small, then you can use a series-expansion of the logarithm $ln(1+y)\approx y-y^2/2$ to get a pretty good approximation of the solution, which can now be written in closed form: `DSolve[{y[s] + y'[s] + A*(y[s] - y[s]^2/2) == 0, y[0] == y0}, y[s], 
  s] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @Roman: Since "you can use a series-expansion of the logarithm " is not based and no numeric example is presented, all that is built on the sand. BTW, according to the question, $x_0/b$ is big.

Comment: @user64494: the conditions on the series-expansion are $\| y_0 \| \ll 1$ and $A > -1$. You're right that the first condition is probably not satisfied, so this is meaningless in the present question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done as follows (`l` is replaced by `L` to avoid a possible misunderstanding).

```
 s=ParametricNDSolve[{r*x[t]+L*x'[t]+a*Log[1 + x[t]/b]==0,x[0]==x0},x,{t,0,2},{r,a,b,L,x0}]
```

Addition.

```
x1 = x[1001, 0.02, 3*10^(-4), 10^5, 10^5] /. s;
x1[1]
```

> 99004.